# Automating Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I have $3$ datasets I'd like to run a `logistic regression` on split into

1. $X_1, y_1$
2. $X_2, y_2$
3. $X_3, y_3$

How can I run a loop so that I can run an automated logistic regression using the X_train, X_test split function from SkLearn and in doing so printing 3 separate accuracy results for each dataset?

To run on one data set of X, y is as follows:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

print('Accuracy:',metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: you could make a list of your files and loop over the files to make a regression for each...

Answer (score 2):

Having $(X1,y1), (X2,y2), (X2,y2)$  saved in a dictionary:

```py
dictionary = {X1:y1, X2:y2, X3:y3}
```

```py
accuracies = []
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(k, v, 
    test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)
    logreg = LogisticRegression()
    logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
    accuracies.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

But it's not really a good way especially when the datasets are too big.

---

So:

```py
accuracies = []
for i in range(1,4):
    X = 'X{}'.format(i)
    y = 'y{}'.format(i)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vars()[X], vars()[y], 
    test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)
    logreg = LogisticRegression()
    logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
    accuracies.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Note: 
in order to access the varibale names which are different in a small part, like here for X1,X2,..., we can use the mentioned method:

```py
import numpy as np
X1= np.arange(1,10)                                                                                                                                
y1=[i**2 for i in X1]                                                                                                                                
X2= np.arange(-5,5)                                                                                                                                
y2=[i**2 for i in X2]                                                                                                                          
for i in range(1,3): 
    X = 'X{}'.format(i) 
    y = 'y{}'.format(i) 
    print('X_{}'.format(i) , vars()[X])
    print('y_{}'.format(i) , vars()[y])
```

Output:

```py
X_1 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
y_1 [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
X_2 [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]
y_2 [25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run I get the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @Novice Python charmer
 My fault, the first approach of using arrays as dictionary keys might have risen the problem. Have you tried the second approach?